# cplex prints a lot to terminal although corresponding parameters are set

Tags: terminal, cplex, ilog

I am using CPLEX in Cpp.
After googling I found out what parameters need to be set to avoid cplex from printing to terminal and I use them like this:

```
IloCplex cplex(model);
std::ofstream logfile("cplex.log");
cplex.setOut(logfile);
cplex.setWarning(logfile);
cplex.setError(logfile);

cplex.setParam(IloCplex::MIPInterval, 1000);//Controls the frequency of node logging when MIPDISPLAY is set higher than 1.
cplex.setParam(IloCplex::MIPDisplay, 0);//MIP node log display information-No display until optimal solution has been found
cplex.setParam(IloCplex::SimDisplay, 0);//No iteration messages until solution
cplex.setParam(IloCplex::BarDisplay, 0);//No progress information
cplex.setParam(IloCplex::NetDisplay, 0);//Network logging display indicator

if ( !cplex.solve() ) {
....
}
```

but yet cplex prints such things:

```
Warning:  Bound infeasibility column 'x11'.
Presolve time = 0.00 sec. (0.00 ticks)

Root node processing (before b&c):
  Real time             =    0.00 sec. (0.01 ticks)
Parallel b&c, 4 threads:
  Real time             =    0.00 sec. (0.00 ticks)
  Sync time (average)   =    0.00 sec.
  Wait time (average)   =    0.00 sec.
                          ------------
Total (root+branch&cut) =    0.00 sec. (0.01 ticks)
```

Is there any way to avoid printing them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what works in C++ according to [cplex parameters doc](https://www.google.se/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=7&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CEQQFjAG&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.lix.polytechnique.fr%2F~liberti%2Fteaching%2Fxct%2Fcplex%2Frefparameterscplex.pdf&ei=_Z0KVY2VOdPSaMS3gtAE&usg=AFQjCNGq_XrnUuC5gZ6eHukerqmV28-ZgQ&sig2=ZMjNVYJzvSm7oVR3pFyTfA):

```
cplex.setOut(env.getNullStream());
cplex.setWarning(env.getNullStream());
cplex.setError(env.getNullStream());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `setOut` method from `IloAlgorithm` class (`IloCplex` inherits from `IloAlgorithm`). You can set a null output stream as a parameter and prevent logging the message on the screen.

Comment: As you can see, I have already used it in the third line of code above.

Comment: Have you tried setting a `null` output instead of logging into a file?

Comment: Yes, but got the same output.